# Capacitive AC to DC power supply noise

Tags: power-supply, noise, circuit-protection, spark

Im using a transformerless capacitive power supply with this simple circuit:
[image]

```
C1: 3.3uF 400V
R1: 480K
D1-D4: 1N4007
Z1: 10V 1W
C2: 470uF
```

But it burned some my microcontrollers sometimes when I plug it to AC source ( I saw a small spark at plugging zone ).

I've used my scope to check its voltage at plugging time and I saw some high voltages (about 40V) on positive output with about 10us duration.

Also I saw negative voltage (about -30V) on it at plugging time.

I used a voltage regulator (AMS1117) and measured the output voltage of it , but the noises were still appear on scope.

But why ? How voltage can be negative after the rectifire diodes? Also I used 100nf ceramic cap but nothing changed . Why capacitors and zener would not affect these noises?

How can I protect my microcontrollers against this plugging noise ?

Comment: It is a simple reactive power supply that 'floats' between a peak positive and negative voltage. You **CANNOT** Earth ground the DC side of the supply as it is "Hot". You can only ground an AC input side. Even so DC output can be a shock hazard. This is why we use transformers for galvanic isolation. *There is nothing clever about this circuit.*

Answer (score 3):

Please don't wire up that circuit as shown. It's illustrative of principles but is quite dangerous without additional components. We don't want to lose any of our fellow enthusiasts!

To be more direct about it - don't use that type of circuit to power your electronics. It's incredibly unsafe unless it and everything connected to it are totally physically isolated. That includes ground nodes, microcontroller GPIOs, everything. It's also very dangerous to work on unless you're completely competent working with high voltages. Please, use a transformer.

To make it safe, things like the following are needed: A fuse, an inrush current limiting resistor or thermistor, C1 must be an X-cap, R1 must be rated for hundreds of volts. We all have to learn somewhere; it's hard to know all of this before we ever hook anything up. So find someone with experience with offline power supplies to look over your shoulder as you go. This isn't the kind of circuit to be cutting one's teeth on without great care.

Why are things blowing up?

If you plug into mains at the instant that mains voltage is near its peak then that surge can shoot through to the output and destroy low voltage components that are connected to it and then propagate down ground nodes, supply nodes, all over the place. There could be some hundreds of voltage anywhere. An inrush limiting resistor will help this a lot. Also, keep Z1 and C2 in parallel but add a current limiting resistor between them and the diode bridge. This will also help suppress voltage surges and noise spikes.

On the other hand, if you plug in as the mains voltage crosses zero then it will be a much smoother turn-on.

There are also all kinds of high voltage spikes and noise that can be seen on AC mains that won't be adequately filtered by the capacitor and zener diode.

So, find a transformer to step down to 9V or 12V or so and then regulate down from there. And, still use a fuse and be careful. Good luck!

Comment: There's some additional explanation and a tear-down of a transformerless power supply design [here](https://hackaday.com/2017/04/04/the-shocking-truth-about-transformerless-power-supplies/).

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by 65Roadster, this type of power supply is very dangerous unless *totally* enclosed in an insulating case.  And that includes whatever it's powering.  And whatever it's powering is connected to.

The negative output of the power supply is not grounded.  If you try to ground it, you will blow one of the diodes.

The negative probe of your scope should be grounded.  Which means that if you connected it to the negative output of your power supply, you probably blew something.  If you didn't connect the negative probe of your scope to the negative of your power supply, then anything you see is largely meaningless, as the negative isn't referenced to ground.

An additional issue with this type of circuit is that it tends to have a very limited power output, set by capacitor C1.  Set C1 too low and you don't get enough current out.  Set C1 too high and you blow Z1.  They are really only useful for a very limited range of applications, most notably small LED lamps.

Comment: Ok , I know its dangerous , but I need it for my project because of the cost of production . Im asking here to find a way to protect it, also I grounded the scope to negative output of curcuit and still not aware why Its negative voltage at output